# How to create a SQL User-Defined Table Type identical to an existing one with a new name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-types

I am trying to create a tool that will find User-Defined Table Types in a database on MS SQL Server that start with `ABC` and then create a new set of User-Defined Table Types that are identical, but with `-X` appended to the end of the name.

So, for instance, if I ran this theoretical tool on an existing SQL database that contains three UDT's named `MyUdt`, `YourUdt`, and `ABCUdt`, the result would be that the database would now contain four UDT's: `MyUdt`, `YourUdt`, `ABCUdt`, and `ABCUdt-X`.

This appears to be rather similar to a question about how to create a UDT that matches a table: [Automatically generate a user defined table type that matches an existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946140)

I know that a SQL database contains the definition of each of its stored procedures as text and this can be queried on the `sys` tables, but it looks like there is no such definition stores for UDTs.

Before I go to the trouble to write code that will unravel an existing UDT into a statement to create a new UDT, can anyone tell me if there is a way to write a command that says, "Hey MS SQL Server, take the UDT `ABCUdt` and create another one exactly like it called `ABCUdt-X`"?

Comment: Do you need triggers and what not copied too or just the bare structure, the table and its columns? And with or without data?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/161368/5203?

Comment: _I am trying to create a tool_ An application? Usng what language? [SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-ver15) is the class library that supports this functionality.

Comment: In SSMS and VS it's able to script the UDT's one at a time.  Copy/paste no?

Comment: @stickybit I am copying a `user defined table type`, *not* a table.

Answer (score 1):

As with User-Defined Tables SQL Server stores the definitions of the User-Defined Table Types and their columns in system views, e.g.:

```sql
drop type if exists dbo.ABCTest;

create type dbo.ABCTest as table (
  TestID int not null,
  TestName nvarchar(50)
);

declare @type_table_object_id int = (
    select type_table_object_id
    from sys.table_types
    where [name] = N'ABCTest'
);
select * from sys.table_types where type_table_object_id = @type_table_object_id;

select * from sys.all_columns where object_id = @type_table_object_id;
```

| name | system_type_id | user_type_id | schema_id | principal_id | max_length | precision | scale | collation_name | is_nullable | is_user_defined | is_assembly_type | default_object_id | rule_object_id | is_table_type | type_table_object_id | is_memory_optimized |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCTest | 243 | 257 | 1 | NULL | -1 | 0 | 0 | NULL | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1778105375 | 0 |

| object_id | name | column_id | system_type_id | user_type_id | max_length | precision | scale | collation_name | is_nullable | is_ansi_padded | is_rowguidcol | is_identity | is_computed | is_filestream | is_replicated | is_non_sql_subscribed | is_merge_published | is_dts_replicated | is_xml_document | xml_collection_id | default_object_id | rule_object_id | is_sparse | is_column_set | generated_always_type | generated_always_type_desc | encryption_type | encryption_type_desc | encryption_algorithm_name | column_encryption_key_id | column_encryption_key_database_name | is_hidden | is_masked | graph_type | graph_type_desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1778105375 | TestID | 1 | 56 | 56 | 4 | 10 | 0 | NULL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NOT_APPLICABLE | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 0 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 1778105375 | TestName | 2 | 231 | 231 | 100 | 0 | 0 | Latin1_General_100_CI_AS | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NOT_APPLICABLE | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 0 | 0 | NULL | NULL |

You could regenerate a SQL definition of a User-Defined Table Type from this information to achieve recreating it with a different name, but as SMor said in the comments it's probably easier to make SMO do that work for you.